# Acceder a propiedad de objeto JavaScript desde otra propiedad del mismo objeto

Tags: javascript

Tengo un problema que no logro resolver tengo el siguiente codigo

```
 _app.listado = {
        diasMin : 0, 
        init: function() {
            load();
            generarGrid();
            loadControlEvents();

        },
        
        datepickerPropiertiesListadoFin :
        {   
           
           minDate:  this.diasMin+"D",
           maxDate: "100D",
           dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
        },
         
    };
```

Tengo el objeto _app.listado, y en la propiedad datepickerPropiertiesListadoFin en minDate manda a llamar a la propiedad del objeto diasMin, pero al momento de ejecutarlo indica que la variable diasMin no está definida, cómo puedo acceder a esa propiedad? he intentado de varias maneras sin lograrlo aun, el error que me marca es el siguiente:

Cannot read property 'diasMin' of undefined

Comment: Me suena lógico que no puedas acceder a propiedades de un elemento que aún estás definiendo y, por otra parte, `this` hace referencia a `datepickerPropiertiesListadoFin` y no a `_app` ni a `_app.listado`.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías cambiar la asignacion de minDate por una función, por ejemplo:

```
minDate:  function(e){
         return e.diasMin + "D";
       },
```

Con esto podrías verificar los elementos dentro de e y puede que ahí esté diasMin, no se si realmente funcione ya que no pude probar el código más allá de resolver el error de Cannot read property 'diasMin' of undefined.